# Executing JavaScript in the event Java applet fails to run

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have a web page with an embedded Java applet that connects to a server on my LAN for the purpose of measuring LAN Speed. The reason I am using a Java applet is because as far as I am aware, Javascript is too inaccurate to use for measuring LAN Speed.

However, I do have an (inaccurate) javascript version that can do a really rough LAN Speed measurement.

How can I tell if the applet successfully ran, and if not, to execute the javascript fallback speed test? I'm using Java 8 and Google Chrome 36.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<applet id="SpeedTester" code="SpeedTester.class" archive="SpeedTester.jar"> 
    <param...>
    <param...>
    <param...>
    <script>alert("Applet Failed to Execute!"); runJSSpeedTest();</script>
</applet>
```

However, it seems as though the code in `<script>` always runs regardless of if Java is installed, disabled, or enabled.

Comment: I think that's a valid answer to my question, by the way, so if you create an actual answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: No, now I look at the HTML closer, it is valid (HTML 3.2), OTOH - the HTML embedded in an applet tag only gets executed if the browser does not *recognize* the applet element.  The only HTML renderer I know of that does not understand what an `applet` element is would be ..`JEditorPane` - and it offers no support for JS.  The attribute closer to what you were trying to achieve (understand Java but Java not installed or not enabled) would be put in the `alt` attribute of the `applet` element.  But stick with JS polling the applet - it is the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applet should provide a method to confirm it loaded OK. A JS should poll the applet for a time, trying each time to access that method with an 'OK' result. It the JS has not received an 'OK' after a certain time limit, use the JS speed test.